# Creating app-like submenus

Tags: mobile, responsive-design

I'm creating a mobile version of my website. The desktop version uses [Bootstrap's Modal frames](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) for editing data records.

On the mobile page, this could be achieved by a seperate page which shows like an iOS submenu (imagine the settings app, when you choose a category, the page swipes and the new menu appears).

How could this effect be made? Is there already a framework which proves this? Is there actually a name for this effect/pattern?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would [mmenu](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/) work for you? I have used it successfully to do something similar, but it is a jquery plugin.

Comment: Exactly what I've been looking for! Thanks a lot!